# Embed external website data from another site (e.g. Amazon)

Tags: java, html, excel, embed

I'm trying to gather all the sales ranks worldwide for a single product on Amazon. Since Amazon don't list this information, the only way to get it is to visit every single product on every single international website, which is time-consuming.

So I'm trying to pull some data from an Amazon product page to display it on my website. I figure if I can gather all the data in real-time somewhere, it will be instantly accessible.

However, I can't seem to get iframes, embed or object to work. I basically want to pull the sales rank (ID = SalesRank) from a page like this:

> [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0082SWC30](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0082SWC30)?*Version*=1&*entries*=0

and display it on my site. The idea is that it will be real-time, and I can just look at my site to view the ranks I want to see. (Also the URL shouldn't harm/spam the Amazon algorithm because of the appended code at the end)

This is what I think is the controlling ID for it:

```
<li id="SalesRank">
```

Is there a way to gather this data in an HTML page somehow, so it updates automatically to match the Amazon version?

For example, my page will display:

> Book Title: Great Expectations | Country: United States | Current
>   Sales Rank: (result here)
>
> Book Title: Great Expectations | Country: United Kingdom | Current
>   Sales Rank: (result here)
>
> Book Title: Great Expectations | Country: Germany | Current Sales
>   Rank: (result here)
>
> Book Title: Great Expectations | Country: Netherlands | Current Sales
>   Rank: (result here)

Etc...

So I'd pull the sales ranks up for the following URLs:

amazon.com/gp/product/B0082SWC30?*Version*=1&*entries*=0

amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B0082SWC30?*Version*=1&*entries*=0

amazon.de/gp/product/B0082SWC30?*Version*=1&*entries*=0

amazon.nl/gp/product/B0082SWC30?*Version*=1&*entries*=0

I've managed to get it into Excel, using the **From Web** function and this array to pull out the data I want:

```
{=MID(INDEX('BookUS'!$A:$A,MATCH(FALSE,ISERROR(SEARCH("Best Sellers Rank",'BookUS'!$A:$A)),0)),28,6)*1}
```

But I'm thinking that the refesh button in Excel is going to explode if I do it in 13 countries on 20 books. I was hoping that pulling it into a web page would be faster and easier, but I can't figure out what code I should use to do it.

iframe seems to be blocked by Amazon, Embed brings up a firefox plugin error and object just displays a blank screen in all the attempts I've made.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of found the answer. It's a bit of a workaround though.

Using the plugin from this answer:https://stackoverflow.com/a/25182446/5279336 in Chrome, I can use 'object' to link to any Amazon product page (or multiple ones), like this:

```
    <div>
<object data="http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0082SWC30?Version=1&entries=0" width="600" height="500"> 
<embed src="http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0082SWC30?Version=1&entries=0" width="600" height="500"> </embed>
</object>
</div>
```

Then I can just list all the products that I want to appear on the page, open the html file from my desktop and check all my ranks in all countries. It'd be nice if I could pull out the specific data I wanted and view in a table for a one glance look, but I'm not sure that's possible using 'object'. Still, it's faster than waiting for Excel to load it all up.